# ¿Porqué surge el siguiente error? "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, sql-server, php7

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined
    at limpiaMetodoPago

Ese es el error que me marca, pero lo que no entiendo es porqué, al iniciar cargar la página tengo creada una tabla vacía con id="tbMetPago" y con las siguientes funciones la lleno con una consulta a una base de datos.

Lo que entiendo es que según mi tabla no tiene celdas y es por ello que marca el error pero lo extraño es que sí las contiene ya que mis funciones si llenan la tabla y queda como la dejo al final.

```html
<table id="tbMetPago" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class = "thead">
      <th style="display:none;"></th>
      <th>Método de pago</th>
      <th>Importe</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id = "tbody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
function agregaMetodosPago() {
  //var tbMetPago = document.getElementById('tbMetPago');
  //var rowCnt = tbMetPago.rows.length;
  var tabla = 1;

  $.getJSON("php/json/tb_MetodoPago.php", { tabla: tabla }, function (result)
  {
    //console.log(result);
    if (result != "")
    {
      if (result != 'algo sucedió con la conexión')
      {
        if (result != 'no se encontraron métodos de pago')
        {
          var longitudJSON = Object.keys(result).length;
          agregaFilaMetodoPago(result, longitudJSON);
        }
        else
        {
          alert(result);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        alert(result);
      }
    }
  });
}

function agregaFilaMetodoPago(json, longitudJSON)
{
  var tbMetPago = document.getElementById('tbMetPago').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  for(var i = 0; i < longitudJSON; i++)
  {
    //console.log(i);
    var tr = tbMetPago.insertRow(i);
    var newText;

    for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {      
      var td = document.createElement('td');          // TABLE DEFINITION.
      td = tr.insertCell(c);

      if(c == 0)
      {
        newText  = document.createTextNode(json[i].Campo);
        td.appendChild(newText);
        td.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
      }
      else if(c == 1)
      {
        newText  = document.createTextNode(json[i].Descripcion);
        td.appendChild(newText);
      }
      else if (c == 2)
      {
        newText  = document.createTextNode("0.0000");
        td.appendChild(newText);
        td.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
      }
    }
  }
}

function limpiaMetodoPago()
{
  var tbMetPago = document.getElementById('tbMetPago');
  for(var i = 1; i <= tbMetPago.rows.length; i++)
  {
    tbMetPago.rows[i+1].cells[2].innerText = "0.0000"; //Línea donde me marca error
  }

}
```

```html
<table id="tbMetPago" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="thead">
      <th style="display:none;"></th>
      <th>Método de pago</th>
      <th>Importe</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        18
      </td>
      <td>
        99 Otros
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        17
      </td>
      <td>
        05 Monedero electrónico
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        16
      </td>
      <td>
        29 Tarjeta de servicio
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        15
      </td>
      <td>
        04 Tarjeta de crédito
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        14
      </td>
      <td>
        28 Tarjeta de debito
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        13
      </td>
      <td>
        02 Cheque nominativo
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        12
      </td>
      <td>
        03 Transferencia electrónica
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        11
      </td>
      <td>
        01 Efectivo
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: me parece raro el `rows[i+1]` si estas empezando tambien desde 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás accediendo a filas de tu tabla que no existen:

Por una parte tienes

```
for(var i = 1; i <= tbMetPago.rows.length; i++)
```

El `for` tendría que ir hasta `i<tbMetPago.rows.length;`

Por otro lado, el `i+1` de `tbMetPago.rows[i+1].cells[2]` no tiene mucho sentido. Piensa que cuando llegues a la última fila vas a acceder al índice i+1 que no existe por lo que vas a obtener un `undefined` y al intentar acceder a `cells` de `undefined` dará error.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
function agregaFilaMetodoPago(json, longitudJSON)
{
  var tbMetPago = document.getElementById('tbMetPago').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  for(var i = 0; i < longitudJSON; i++)
  {
    //console.log(i);
    var tr = tbMetPago.insertRow(i);
    var newText;

    for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {      
      var td = document.createElement('td');          // TABLE DEFINITION.
      td = tr.insertCell(c);

      if(c == 0)
      {
        newText  = document.createTextNode(json[i].Campo);
        td.appendChild(newText);
        td.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
      }
      else if(c == 1)
      {
        newText  = document.createTextNode(json[i].Descripcion);
        td.appendChild(newText);
      }
      else if (c == 2)
      {
        newText  = document.createTextNode("0.0000");
        td.appendChild(newText);
        td.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
      }
    }
  }
}

function limpiaMetodoPago()
{
  var tbMetPago = document.getElementById('tbMetPago');
  for(var i = 1; i < tbMetPago.rows.length; i++)
  {
    tbMetPago.rows[i].cells[2].innerText = "0.0000"; //Línea donde me marca error
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="tbMetPago" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="thead">
      <th style="display:none;"></th>
      <th>Método de pago</th>
      <th>Importe</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        18
      </td>
      <td>
        99 Otros
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        2.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        17
      </td>
      <td>
        05 Monedero electrónico
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        1.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        16
      </td>
      <td>
        29 Tarjeta de servicio
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0200
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        15
      </td>
      <td>
        04 Tarjeta de crédito
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        1.2000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        14
      </td>
      <td>
        28 Tarjeta de debito
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        13
      </td>
      <td>
        02 Cheque nominativo
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        12
      </td>
      <td>
        03 Transferencia electrónica
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        11
      </td>
      <td>
        01 Efectivo
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">
        0.0000
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Limpiar" onclick="limpiaMetodoPago()"/>
```

Comment: Gracias!, sí es ese el error. Lo había hecho así porque anteriormente lo había dejado como "tbMetPago.rows[i+1].cells[2]" y me modificaba también la cabecera, pero ahora no, quizá tenía otra cosa mal y no me percaté de ello.

Comment: El contador ahora lo inicias con 1 lo que significa que te saltas la cabecera que esta en la posicion 0, por lo que no hace falta el `i + 1`